# A differential equation having a solution everywhere except of a certain point?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need an example of an ordinary differential equation which has (unique) solutions of initial value problems on $(-\infty;a)$ and $(a;+\infty)$ but not in a real number $a$.

I think, the simpler example is the better. Please also provide me with the solutions.

Comment: Probably the example solutions should go to infinity near $a$.

Comment: Invert the problem start from a function and differentiate

Comment: @Isham $\frac{d(1/x)}{dx}=-1/x^2$. Oh, it it an equation I need.

Comment: @Isham Well, is the solution unique?

Answer (score 1):

$xy'(x)=y(x)$ with initial condition $y(0)=0$ has infinitely many solutions on the real line, $y(x)=Cx$.

Conversely, the same equation with initial condition $y(0)=1$ has no solutions.

In both cases, the coefficient of $y'(x)$ vanishes at $x=0$, which causes the pathology.  If the initial condition is specified for $x\neq 0$, then solutions of the IVP are unique, as easily verified.